# Format km.coxph.plot output using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

Is it possible to format the `km.coxph.plot` using ggplot?

```
km.coxph.plot(formula.s=formula(Surv(time, event) ~ gg), data.s=dd, sub.s="all", x.label="Time (years)", y.label="Survival", main.title="", sub.title="", leg.text=c("Low   ", "Intermediate   ", "High   "), leg.pos="right", leg.inset=0.05,leg.bty = "0",  o.text=FALSE, v.line=FALSE, h.line=FALSE, .col=c("darkblue", "darkgreen", "darkred"), .lty=1, show.n.risk=TRUE, n.risk.step=1, n.risk.cex=0.85, verbose=FALSE, ylim=c(0.3,1))
```

And how do I get the legend smaller?

[image]

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you make a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to solve your problem. You can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.